# iOS: Is it possible to detect a non finger touch?

Tags: objective-c

I have an app that expects a coin to be placed on top of the phone after it's loaded. Would it be possible to detect the coin and the surface area that is touching the phone? I want to create a circle around the edges of the coin.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Is there a gesture recognizer for it?

Comment: You don't know how to do what? Put a coin on an iPhone. What happens?

Comment: I don't know if a gesture recognizer exists for this type of thing

Comment: Edmund, you should have learned by now that you shouldn't put tags in the title of your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hardware responds to certain kinds of conductivity, such as that of human skin. You will have to experiment to see what happens with different types of coin. Even if the hardware can detect the coin, the software will reduce the touch to a point. The iPhone is not in the business of detecting coin shapes any more than it is in the business of detecting finger shapes. Thus, your app will be unable to find out exactly where the coin is.

Comment: Found [something interesting](https://easyplace.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/how-to-detect-touch-size-in-ios/) by googling. What's your opinion on that?

Comment: Well, it's obvious enough that the `majorRadius` property exists; you could have found that out just by consulting the documentation. But the fact remains that describing coin shapes is not the function of the iPhone surface. That is why I asked you what happened when you tried it. You need to try it with various coins and see what happens!